# Why can't I append an outerHTML to an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to grab an element that is positioned in a certain place on the page and insert into an element that is in another area of the page. I thought by taking the element with **outerHTML** property and using the **appendChild** method would allow me to insert the element.But, when I run the program I get an error message saying that **Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object**

```js
/* This is for clicking off the overlay */
(function removeOverlay(){
document.querySelector('div.overlay span a').onclick = function()
{
document.querySelector('div.overlay').style.display ="none";
console.log('I am closing')
};

document.querySelector('div.overlay').addEventListener('click', function(){

this.style.display ="none";
console.log('Im closing with overlay');

});

})();


/* Activates the overlay */
document.querySelector('button#overlay-on').addEventListener('click',function(){

var overlay = document.querySelector('div.overlay');
overlay.style.display = "block";

var message = document.querySelector('div#message').outerHTML;
var relative = document.querySelector('div.rela');


document.getElementById('message').setAttribute('style','position:absolute; display:block; top:10%; ');
var text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('message').offsetWidth);
document.querySelector('div#message p').appendChild(text);

relative.appendChild(message);
```

```css
div.overlay{ height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background:rgba(40, 0, 77,0.7); position:fixed; z-index:100; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
    
div.rela{height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative; z-index:101;}

div.rela span{ position:absolute; top:0; left:98%; font-weight:bold;  font-size:36px; }

div.rela span a{ color:white; text-decoration:none; z-index:152;}

div#message{width:40%; height:20%; background:white; text-align:center; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold; display:none; z-index:102;}

div#message h5{font-size:18px;}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="rela">

    <span><a href="#">X</a></span>
  </div><!-- end of rela -->
</div><!-- end of overlay -->

<div id="ex1"><h2>Example 1</h2><p></p><h4>results:</h4>

  <button id="overlay-on">Open up the overlay</button>

  <div id="message">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Width is:</p>
  </div><!-- end of message -->

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example using https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Cleiton these days its better to just encourage posters to use a stack snippet.

Comment: @Cleiton Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7phkg2g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendChild` only accepts true html nodes as its parameter as you can see looking up at [DOM Level 3 Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107)

To solve your problem, you must first create an element using `document.createElement` method, example:

```
(...)
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = message;
relative.appendChild(wrapper);
(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

on your example javascript code, it seems you have forgotten to close:

```
document.querySelector('button#overlay-on').addEventListener('click',function(){
```

with a

```
});
```

and when i close it, it seems working. is this the problem? Or maybe you have a cross-browser issue?

Comment: No I did have a closing bracket with a semi colon. I guess I just didn't copy all of the javascript code and apply it in the message